# Configure Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi without Monitor/Keyboard

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Core for the first time on a Raspberry Pi3. I'm following the directions here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3

The directions explain that on the first boot, you must connect a monitor and keyboard to configure the device. As far as I can tell the configuration consists mostly of downloading your ssh key from your Ubuntu SSO account.

My problem is I don't have an monitor and keyboard. It seems possible, one could open the SD and manually insert the ssh keys where needed. Any ideas how one could configure Ubuntu Core on raspberry pi without a monitor/keyboard?

Comment: From the instructions: (...) *You can alternatively use a serial cable*

Comment: i only have a ethernet cable... and laptop, which worked well for installing raspbian and the like...